# Terminology like "in the direction of $(1, 1, 1)$"

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

Consider $\text{span}\{(1, 1, 1),~(0, 0, 0)\}$. It's a line through the origin. That much I understand, but why is it "in the direction of $(1, 1, 1)$"? Is it another way of saying $(1, 1, 1)$ lies on the line?

Comment: In this case, the vector $(1,1,1)$ does lie on that line, but in general the phrase "A line from point $A$ in the direction of vector $V$" means that the line and the vector are parallel

Comment: @ Rob Bland, I see what's up. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any vector in the span is of the form

$$t (1, 1, 1) + s (0, 0, 0) = t (1, 1, 1)$$

for some scalars $s$ and $t$. Scalar multiplication doesn't change the direction of a vector (aside from, perhaps, reversing it), so it makes sense to say that the direction of every non-zero vector in this span is the same as (up to reversing) the direction of $(1, 1, 1)$.

Comment: I think span is only defined on vector spaces together over a field.

Comment: Is $(1, 1, 1)$ considered to face positive direction starting from the origin? Then, say, $(-1, -1, -1)$ would face in the other direction, right? Can you elaborate on that a bit more, please.

Comment: @integer I wouldn't really say it has "positive" direction, since that doesn't make much sense in $\mathbb{R}^3$; it does lie in the first octant, though. The vector $(-1, -1, -1)$ does point in the opposite direction.

Comment: @Imago Yes, but if you have a vector space there is an underlying scalar field. That's where $s, t$ are from.